# Error occurred while restoring NuGet packages: The MSBuildProjectExtensionsPath MSBuild property could not be found for project Setup.wixproj

Tags: msbuild, wix, nuget

We have legacy application that have been created by older versino of visual studio and wix. The last version worked with is Visual Studio 2015.
After using VS2019 we are starting to have issues when restoring packages:
Error occurred while restoring NuGet packages: The MSBuildProjectExtensionsPath MSBuild property could not be found for project Setup.wixproj

version of WiX 3.11.4516.0
version of Visual Studio: Visual Studio 2019 (16.3.6)
WiX Toolset Visual Studio Extension 1.0.0.4
The projects use .NET framework 4.5.2

When i create a new wixsetup project , i notice that the layout is different.
I tried to change the properties one by one to figure which one was the problem but i never managed to get rid of the error

here is my wixproj

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003" ToolsVersion="4.0">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Release</Configuration>
    <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">x64</Platform>
    <ProductVersion>3.0</ProductVersion>
    <ProjectGuid>{99f1ae14-c5d9-4153-b9be-d4e5d6da2a2c}</ProjectGuid>
    <SchemaVersion>2.0</SchemaVersion>
    <OutputName>Setup</OutputName>
    <OutputType>Package</OutputType>
    <WixTargetsPath Condition=" '$(WixTargetsPath)' == '' AND '$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)' != '' ">$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\WiX\v3.x\Wix.targets</WixTargetsPath>
    <WixTargetsPath Condition=" '$(WixTargetsPath)' == '' ">$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\Microsoft\WiX\v3.x\Wix.targets</WixTargetsPath>
    <SccProjectName>SAK</SccProjectName>
    <SccProvider>SAK</SccProvider>
    <SccAuxPath>SAK</SccAuxPath>
    <SccLocalPath>SAK</SccLocalPath>
    <RunWixToolsOutOfProc>True</RunWixToolsOutOfProc>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|x64' ">
    <DefineConstants>Debug</DefineConstants>
    <OutputPath>bin\$(Platform)\$(Configuration)\</OutputPath>
    <IntermediateOutputPath>obj\$(Platform)\$(Configuration)\</IntermediateOutputPath>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|x64' ">
    <OutputPath>bin\$(Platform)\$(Configuration)\</OutputPath>
    <IntermediateOutputPath>obj\$(Platform)\$(Configuration)\</IntermediateOutputPath>
    <SuppressAllWarnings>False</SuppressAllWarnings>
    <Pedantic>True</Pedantic>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="UI_InstallDir.wxs" />
    <Compile Include="Product.wxs" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\WindowsService1\WindowsService1.csproj">
      <Name>WindowsService1</Name>
      <Project>{720823ef-c775-4112-a906-b079ea977513}</Project>
      <Private>True</Private>
    </ProjectReference>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <WixExtension Include="WixNetFxExtension">
      <HintPath>$(WixExtDir)\WixNetFxExtension.dll</HintPath>
      <Name>WixNetFxExtension</Name>
    </WixExtension>
    <WixExtension Include="WixUtilExtension">
      <HintPath>$(WixExtDir)\WixUtilExtension.dll</HintPath>
      <Name>WixUtilExtension</Name>
    </WixExtension>
    <WixExtension Include="WixUIExtension">
      <HintPath>$(WixExtDir)\WixUIExtension.dll</HintPath>
      <Name>WixUIExtension</Name>
    </WixExtension>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="Images\" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="Images\Banner.bmp" />
    <Content Include="Images\Dialog.bmp" />
    <Content Include="project.json" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <Import Project="$(WixTargetsPath)" />

</Project>
```

Comment: do you get the same error on the new wix project? did you compare all differences, or just the properties?

Answer (score 0):

I am going to answer by posting what I did although I am not sure about the mechanics behind:
there have been som breaking changes since MSBuild 15 (visual studio 2017) and it seems the Wix team updated their Wixproj template format to support it: https://github.com/wixtoolset/issues/issues/5525
I only had to create a new project from the new template (moved my items to the projects) and build. It seems to do the trick.